# Weird stair-step effect on back face edges with pixel blending and MSAA enabled

Tags: graphics, directx, directx-12

I'm implementing a renderer in DirectX 12 and noticed a weird visual issue: when using pixel blending and MSAA enabled edges of back faces are seem to be anti-aliased weirdly and I can see inner edges as a 1-pixel size line.

It will probably be hard to see this in the following screenshot so I drew a red line (in Paint) near the edges. As you may see there is a dark-grey 1-pixel line that goes along the inner edges (near the red line).

[image]

Here is better screenshot (zoomed in) of an inner edge of a red cube (screenshot from PIX):

[image]

PIX says that alpha is 0.5 (as expected) but the color is changing along the edge.

This weird effect happens only when MSAA is enabled with pixel blending, once I disable MSAA everything looks correct. Moreover if I switch to my integrated GPU Intel 630 there are no issues with transparency and MSAA. This only happens on my dedicated GPU NVIDIA 1060. I've tried updating the drivers just in case but it didn't helped. One of my friends was also able to see internal lines but only when using NVIDIA GPU.

Did anybody had such issue? How to debug the source of this issue?

Here is a small code sample of PSO creation:

```
// Setup rasterizer description.
CD3DX12_RASTERIZER_DESC rasterizerDesc(D3D12_DEFAULT);
rasterizerDesc.CullMode = D3D12_CULL_MODE_NONE;
rasterizerDesc.FillMode = D3D12_FILL_MODE_SOLID;
rasterizerDesc.MultisampleEnable = 1;
psoDesc.RasterizerState = rasterizerDesc;

// Setup pixel blend description.
psoDesc.BlendState = CD3DX12_BLEND_DESC(D3D12_DEFAULT);
D3D12_RENDER_TARGET_BLEND_DESC blendDesc;
blendDesc.BlendEnable = 1;
blendDesc.LogicOpEnable = 0;
blendDesc.SrcBlend = D3D12_BLEND_SRC_ALPHA;
blendDesc.DestBlend = D3D12_BLEND_INV_SRC_ALPHA;
blendDesc.BlendOp = D3D12_BLEND_OP_ADD;
blendDesc.SrcBlendAlpha = D3D12_BLEND_ONE;
blendDesc.DestBlendAlpha = D3D12_BLEND_ZERO;
blendDesc.BlendOpAlpha = D3D12_BLEND_OP_ADD;
blendDesc.LogicOp = D3D12_LOGIC_OP_NOOP;
blendDesc.RenderTargetWriteMask = D3D12_COLOR_WRITE_ENABLE_ALL;
psoDesc.BlendState.RenderTarget[0] = blendDesc;
psoDesc.BlendState.AlphaToCoverageEnable = 0;

// Finalize PSO description.
psoDesc.DepthStencilState = CD3DX12_DEPTH_STENCIL_DESC(D3D12_DEFAULT);
// Disable depth writes.
psoDesc.DepthStencilState.DepthWriteMask = D3D12_DEPTH_WRITE_MASK_ZERO;
psoDesc.SampleMask = UINT_MAX;
psoDesc.PrimitiveTopologyType = D3D12_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TYPE_TRIANGLE;
psoDesc.NumRenderTargets = 1;
psoDesc.RTVFormats[0] = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
psoDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 8;
psoDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = iMsaaQualityLevelsCount - 1;
psoDesc.DSVFormat = DXGI_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT;
```

MSAA render target resource also has the same sample count / quality levels enabled.

Comment: Why are you disabling depth writes?

Comment: @MaicoDeBlasio To see through transparent objects.